# Docusign auto populate to tabs with data validation not working

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm using docusign-php-client, I have set up the template and the tabs on Dosusign website.

In the template, I have a Text tab called "fee_a", and the data I was trying to autofill is "20":

- when tab validation is set to "Numbers", the data is not able to get auto-populated;
- when set to "None", data is able to get through to the form with no problem.

I have to use validation for this tab in the template, because there is a formula tab need to use it.

Here is my php code to populate value to the tab:

```
        $DataArr["fee_a"] = "20";

        $tab_hld = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
        /* also tried 
            $tab_hld = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Number(); 
           got same result */

        $tab_hld->setTabLabel("\\*fee_a");
        $tab_hld->setValue($DataArr["fee_a"]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out.

For those who has the same issue, you will have to use setNumberTabs(instead of setTextTabs) function for those tabs with "Number" validation.

```
$tabs->setNumberTabs(array($tab_a, $tab_hld));
```