# Unable To Use Docusign API to populate a text field(with Number validation) in my template

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have a template in Docusign with a Text field with the following settings:

Data Label : 'Demolition'

Validation : Numbers

I try to use the Docusign Nodejs client to populate this field like so :

```
let demolition = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
                            tabLabel: "Demolition", value: args.demolition});
let builderTabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({

                numberTabs: [demolition]          

                            });
```

I use numberTabs because using textTabs does not work and the link below suggests using numberTabs.

[Docusign auto populate to tabs with data validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438079/docusign-auto-populate-to-tabs-with-data-validation-not-working)

But that does not work either.

This is the error I receive from Docusign when I use 'numberTabs' 
 text: '{\r\n  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",\r\n  "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."\r\n}',

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following code and it worked (make sure you update the `tabLabel` to the same label you have in your template):

```
var envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.emailSubject = 'Please sign this document sent from Node SDK';
envDef.templateId = templateId;

// create a template role with a valid templateId and roleName and assign signer info
var tRole = new docusign.TemplateRole();
tRole.roleName = roleName;
tRole.name = 'Sally Doe';
tRole.email = 'sally@email.com';

tRole.tabs = new docusign.Tabs();
tRole.tabs.numberTabs = [];

var nTab = new docusign.Text();
nTab.tabLabel = "myLabel";
nTab.value = "123";
tRole.tabs.numberTabs.push(nTab);

// create a list of template roles and add our newly created role
var templateRolesList = [];
templateRolesList.push(tRole);

// assign template role(s) to the envelope
envDef.templateRoles = templateRolesList;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response and the code. But this doesn't work for me when I apply a Number validation on the tab in my template.

Comment: Please elaborate, what happens when you try it?  Do you get an error?  If so what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to set a value for a tab that is defined in a template is to use a `role` object as Ergin shows in his answer.

You were trying to *create* a new Number tab. I believe there is a problem with the Node.js SDK that currently prevents it from creating Number tabs. (`Number` is a reserved work in Javascript and this is causing a problem.)